# Working in Angular js with remote REST API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, rest, api

I want to know if there is some way to call remote REST API call within an angular js .

As of now, I have a setup like , 
bower for dependency management ,
grunt for server and other build task runner (minification,compression,).
angular js as front-end framework.

I have my REST API deployed on server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9090 . and I have configured CORS filters on my server .

If I access my rest API within angular js app, it makes two requests one with option  and another with properly HTTP verbs .

On many blogs, I found that opening CORS filter on the server is a security risk.

So is there any safe way to do that without enabling CORS on my server , and consuming REST API in angular without any domain problem.

As i am running angular app on my localhost and REST API is deployed remotly

And after building application using grunt I am running it in tomcat server . I know this is not good but right now I don't have any choice apart from that due to various access issues on client side

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your code man ? without code only God can help you :)

Comment: for call rest api you can use pure javascript too

Comment: there is no need for code here

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way,

if you are using grunt, you can use grunt-connect-proxy to route your certain call to different server API.

If you are using apache, you can set proxypass.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that I am using tomcat to run the application , as I don't have node/software on the server for deployment . As angular application are on client side so every ajax request hitting another server apart from my server domain where application is deployed .